# How does port mapped I/O and I/O mapped I/O work

Tags: cpu, input, chipset

Port mapped I/O uses separate addresses for ports in a separate address space. Now the first thing I want to make sure I have correct understanding of address space ,it's a range of addresses for a certain thing like memory , a program or a device . Now as mentioned earlier port mapped I/O uses port addresses for accessing I/O devices in a separate address space so now suppose a 32-bit cpu createe an address that's 32-bits wide are parts of those addresses for memory and others are for I/O if so ,what is the difference between this type of I/O and memory mapped I/O and why are I/O instructios required for this type of I/O,if not then what is actually meant by a separate address space and what's actually an address space .

Also explain how does I/O mapped I/O work in different architectures and systems that have a chipset and that chipset is connected the cpu through the front side bus (the cpu doesn'thave any connection to memory or I/O devices) like how does the chipset know the cpu is accessing memory or I/o devices.

Comment: That last paragraph is a bit too "stream of consciousness"; would you be so kind to turn that in one or more proper questions? For fun I tried ChatGPT and it gave pretty decent answers.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southbridge_(computing) & 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northbridge_(computing) & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O_and_port-mapped_I/O

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You may find this information on the internet. Learning materials are off-subject here.

Comment: @Gantendo what I meant with the last paragraph is suppose you have a cpu connected to a chipset though the front side bus and the cpu performs a memory access or port mapped I/O operation how would the chipset know if that is memory or an I/O port address if they are both addresses

Comment: @Gantendo I actually tried chatgpt an still can't understand any thing because most of the time it just says different contradicting things or it answers the same answer when asking about a detail in answers. And I also saw all of the Wikipedia sites you mentioned before and I still don't understand where the chipset part comes into play

Comment: "*I/O mapped I/O*" is a nonsense word combination. It's simply port addressing versus memory addressing.  You need to study the instruction set for the CPU; try the Intel i8086. There are instructions that load from or store to memory addresses. There are also instructions that read or write to port addresses. It's the instruction opcode that the CPU executes that determine how the I/O is performed.

Answer (score 0):

> How does port mapped I/O and I/O mapped I/O work

Your title makes no sense. "*I/O mapped I/O*" is a nonsense work combination.
Presumably you're trying to compare port mapping versus memory mapping.

> Port mapped I/O uses separate addresses for ports in a separate address space.

Port-mapped I/O corresponds to specific CPU instructions to utilize this address space. Since accessing a port implies data transfer to a peripheral, the opcodes for such instructions typically have mnemonics like IN and OUT, and one of the operands would be a port address.

The instruction opcodes for transfer to/from memory addresses typically have mnemonics like LOAD and STOR(e), or (the ambiguous) MOV(e).

Since port addresses are distinct from memory addresses and the number of ports is not that large, the port address space is likely to be smaller than memory address space. For instance the Intel i8086 had 20-bit memory addresses (to address one megabytes of memory), but had port addresses only 16 bits wide.

---

[Breakdown of a long run-on sentence/question]

> ... so now suppose a 32-bit cpu createe an address that's 32-bits wide are parts of those addresses for memory and others are for I/O

No, an address will only reference one space.
Port addresses may have its own bus or share an address bus with memory (with a status line to indicate the type of address). This is an implementation detail that depends on the CPU.

> if so ,what is the difference between this type of I/O and memory mapped I/O and

Your questions have no context.
In reality the CPU will operate within a computer system. Peripherals and device interfaces (aka controllers) will be connected to the CPU to form that system. The system designers have assigned either port addresses or "memory" addresses to all the registers of these devices.
The type of address assignment for each device has to be known when the code (e.g. device driver) is written. The software has to use the proper port or memory instructions because each device register only responds to the address & bus to which it has been assigned & connected.

The actual data transfer between CPU and device/port register is effectively identical with either a port or memory-mapped I/O instruction. Low-level bus signalling and timing may differ, but these two methods of performing I/O (by using different instructions) accomplish the same thing.

> why are I/O instructios required for this type of I/O,

An "*I/O instruction*" by definition uses a port address as one of its operands for either the source or destination of the transfer.

A memory instruction uses a memory address as one of its operands for either the source or destination of the transfer. Such a memory reference will access RAM when RAM is mapped at that address, or a device register will be accessed when a peripheral is mapped at that address.

> if not then what is actually meant by a separate address space and what's actually an address space .

Such basic concepts are probably easily explained by (crude) analogy.

Image a town with exactly two streets. All the commercial buildings in town are located on one street, and all the residential houses are located on the other street.

Image another town with just one street. All buildings and houses are located on this single street.

Each street uses an address composed of a simple number. The street address could specify either a business or home.

In the town with just one street, if you just had the address (number), you really wouldn't need the street name because there's only one street (assuming you're in the correct town).
But if you're in the first town with two streets, you need the complete address of both the number and street name to get to where you want to go.

An address space is analogous to the set of (building/house) numbers of a street (in either town).
Separate address spaces is analogous to the two streets in the first town. Each street has its own address space, i.e. set of numbers. A (street) number could be duplicated in each set, or could be unique to one set.

Of course the commercial buildings correspond to ports, and residential houses correspond to memory cells.

---

Apparently you're only familiar with Von Neumann computer architecture where (main) memory is used for both instructions and data. But there's also the Harvard computer architecture which has one memory space for instructions and another, separate memory space for data.